# Does the function exist?

Tags: calculus

Does the function which satisfies the following conditions exist:

1. It is continuous on the segment $[a, b]$;
2. It is not equals to the identical zero (it means that $f(x)$ may equal $0$, but not on the whole  $[a, b]$ segment);
3. $\forall$ segment $[\alpha, \beta] \subset [a, b]$ $\exists$ segment $[\alpha ', \beta '] \subset [\alpha, \beta]$ where $f(x) = 0$?

---

What I think is that this function may exist if it has non-zero values in $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ and $f(x') = 0$ where $x' \in (a, b)$ but I don't know how to write it properly.

Comment: Hint: consider a point at which the function is non-zero. What does continuity then imply?

Comment: @Denis your construction: then it's not continuous at a and b

Comment: @MarkBennet ... that there's an interval around that point, where it's all non-zero => contradiction

Answer (score 2):

The idea of the argument is this :

Suppose that there exists x such that $f(x) = \epsilon > 0$.

Then by continuity, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\forall y \in [x-\delta, x+\delta], f(y) > \frac{\epsilon}{2}$

But on this segment, there is no segment where $f$ is equal to zero